# AlertDialog.dismiss() not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am not using the negative and positive buttons. I need to close the dialog but dialog.dismiss() has no effect.

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setView(view);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        dialog = alert.create();
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //goButton is inside view which is inflated inside the dialog

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                age = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
                if(gender == null){
                    Utils.makeToast(context, "Select your gender");
                }else if(age == null || age.toLowerCase().contains("age") || age.equals("")){
                    spinner.performClick();
                }else{
                    Utils.makeToast(context, (String)spinner.getSelectedItem() + " - gender: " +gender);
                    editor.putInt("age", Utils.getIntOrZero(age));
                    editor.putString("gender", gender);
                    editor.commit();
                    dialog.dismiss(); // called but not working
                }
            }
        });

        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't dismissing because the `AlertDialog` you're calling `AlertDialog.dismiss` on isn't the same one that's shown. In other words, you're calling `alert.show()` and using `dialog.dismiss()`. To fix it call `dialog.show()`.

Comment: Made an edit, you're calling `AlertDialog.dismiss` on the wrong `AlertDialog`.